# Android Show Random Questions

Tags: android

How can i Show random questions. I looked in the other posts but the answers there didn't work . This has 3 difficulty easy medium hard . i want to make the questions random per difficulty . thanks

QuizActivity:

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    int score = 0;
    int qnum = 1;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc, rdd;
    Button butNext;
    RadioGroup rdgrp;

    String corAnswer = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        rdgrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.questionAndAnswers);
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rdd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        butNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        corAnswer = "";
        onCreateQuestion();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void onCreateQuestion() {
        String level = getIntent().getExtras().getString("level");
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        db.getQuestByLevel(level, qnum);

        txtQuestion.setText(db.question);
        rda.setText(db.optionA);
        rdb.setText(db.optionB);
        rdc.setText(db.optionC);
        rdd.setText(db.optionD);
        corAnswer = db.answer;

        qnum++;

    }

    public void onClickNext(View view) {
        String level = getIntent().getExtras().getString("level");
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        db.getQuestByLevel(level, qnum);

        RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.questionAndAnswers);
        RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        if (answer == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "select an answer please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            return;
        }
        if (corAnswer!= null && corAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase((String) answer.getText()))
        {
            score++;
            Log.d("answer", "Your score" + score);
        }
        if (qnum <= 5) {


        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        txtQuestion.setText(db.question);
        rda.setText(db.optionA);
        rdb.setText(db.optionB);
        rdc.setText(db.optionC);
        rdd.setText(db.optionD);
        corAnswer = db.answer;
        qnum++;
        rdgrp.clearCheck();
    }


}
```

Database:

```
 public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "QUIZ";
    private static final String TABLE_QUIZ = "quiz";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta";
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb";
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc";
    private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd";
    private static final String q_level = "level";
    private static final String QuestionNumber = "q_number";
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public String question, optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, answer;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUIZ + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD  +" TEXT, " + q_level + " TEXT, " + QuestionNumber + " INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','1')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q2','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','2')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q3','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','3')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q4','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','4')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q5','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','EASY','5')");



        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','1')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','2')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','3')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','4')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','MEDIUM','5')");


        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','1')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','2')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','3')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','4')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUIZ + "(" + KEY_QUES + ", " + KEY_OPTA + ", " + KEY_OPTB + ", " + KEY_OPTC + ", " + KEY_OPTD + ", " + KEY_ANSWER + ", " + q_level + ", " + QuestionNumber + ")VALUES(" +
                "'Q1','A1','A2','A3','A4','Answer','HARD','5')");
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }

    private void addQuestions() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUIZ);
        onCreate(db);
    }



    public void getQuestByLevel(String level, int qnum) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ + " WHERE " + q_level  +" = '" + level + "' AND "+QuestionNumber+" = "+qnum+"" ;


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                question=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUES));
                optionA=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTA));
                optionB=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTB));
                optionC=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTC));
                optionD=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTD));
                answer=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER));


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
 01-22 23:23:41.285    8685-8685/com.dreamteam.quiz.project 
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dreamteam.quiz.project, PID: 8685
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dreamteam.quiz.project/com.example.quiz.project.QuizActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE level = 'EASY' AND q_number = 1 + ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2319)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE level = 'EASY' AND q_number = 1 + ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1112)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:689)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1372)
            at com.example.quiz.project.DbHelper.getQuestByLevel(DbHelper.java:97)
            at com.example.quiz.project.QuizActivity.onCreateQuestion(QuizActivity.java:60)
            at com.example.quiz.project.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:45)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5296)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your query have syntax errors: remove +(PLUS)  before ORDER BY and also make sure that query must ends by ;(semicolon)

Comment: @kishorepatel i tried String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ + " WHERE " + q_level  +" = '" + level + "' AND "+QuestionNumber+" = "+qnum+"  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5 " ; but it didnt give me random questions

Comment: For LEVEL 1 and QuestionNumber = 1, there is only one tuple so you will be getting only one row in the result. Obviously one row cannot be have any randomness.

Comment: Let me give you one idea; Run this query as it is an see what happens **selectquery = "SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE level = 'EASY' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5;";** If this works then you can be sure that problem is only in query logic or in commas and quotations

Comment: it worked, but how to show now the medium and hard difficulty?

Comment: Use this and now on try to change thing yourself & learn SQL from online sources => **selectquery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ +" WHERE "+ q_level  +" = '"+ level  +"' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5;";**

Comment: @kishorepatel uhm last question . how to make the question not repeat ?

Comment: The SQL query will have no question repeated. You need not worry about that.

Comment: i just tried the app some questions actually repeats

Comment: ok, then use create a Model Class as shown by my answer below and dump all the query data from cursor into that Array and then randomize it and take the questions from TOP indexes which will sure be random and without repititions NOTE: Sql query remove the LIMIT and rather get all the question of the needed level---Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

**Use query:**

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ + " WHERE " + q_level  +" = '" + level + "' AND "+QuestionNumber+" = "+qnum+" + ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"  ;
```

I think by changing the query you can attend the solution.

Comment: sorry it will be RANDOM(). please check and let me know if the app still crashes

Comment: the app still crashes

Answer (score 0):

Store results in a Model class and then randomize it.

```
class Question{
    int id;
    String questionText;
    String[] options;
}


Question[] questions = new Question[cursor.size()];
//put data into questions
Random rnd = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < question.length; i++){
    //using randomizer swap objects
}
```

Now select to TOP 5 or 10 or 20 question which you want to show, there will be no duplicate and will also be random order

Comment: in my declared codes . can't i just randomize it there ?

Comment: Look at the solution of Sumit Chakroborty if that works. Use random() for sqlite and LIMIT 5; (or the number you want) and I don't know about its speed. Also see this like for writing query http://blog.rodolfocarvalho.net/2012/05/how-to-select-random-rows-from-sqlite.html Hope that helps

Comment: i tried this code : 
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUIZ + " WHERE " + q_level +" = '" + level + "' AND "+QuestionNumber+" = "+qnum+" + ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5" ; 

but still it didn't give random question.